# check numbers in one textbox delete line in all in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, textbox, listbox

i have 6 textboxs in total box4 has a range of numbers 1.76, 5.6 2.89 etc. i want to check if the number is over 2 and if so delete and then delete that line in the 5 other text boxes, i know its a mess 
 i changed my code it will work from some figures but not others

```
      Dim list1 As List(Of String) = TextBox1.Lines.ToList
    Dim list2 As List(Of String) = TextBox2.Lines.ToList
    Dim list3 As List(Of String) = TextBox3.Lines.ToList
    Dim list4 As List(Of String) = TextBox4.Lines.ToList
    Dim list5 As List(Of String) = TextBox5.Lines.ToList
    Dim list6 As List(Of String) = TextBox6.Lines.ToList
    Dim t As Int32
    Dim lin As String

    t = 1
    lin = TextBox4.Lines(t).ToString()

    Do Until t = TextBox4.Lines.Count

        If lin > 2 Then


            list1.RemoveAt(t)
            TextBox1.Lines = list1.ToArray
            list2.RemoveAt(t)
            TextBox2.Lines = list2.ToArray
            list3.RemoveAt(t)
            TextBox3.Lines = list3.ToArray
            list5.RemoveAt(t)
            TextBox5.Lines = list5.ToArray
            list6.RemoveAt(t)
            TextBox6.Lines = list6.ToArray
            list4.RemoveAt(t)
            TextBox4.Lines = list4.ToArray

            t += 1

        End If

    Loop
```

Comment: Try `TextBox2.Lines(i).Remove(0, TextBox2.Lines(i).Length - 1)` in place of `TextBox2.Lines(i) = ""` for all of your TextBoxes.

Comment: no sorry it didnt work, it gives error

Comment: Yeah sorry, that would do the same as what you have anyway since it just returns an empty string. What you're asking for seems strange. Maybe we could get a better idea if you added some screenshots of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what your example code is going to do.

What you can do is trap the 'validating' event of the textbox and then update the other textboxes in the code you run when this event is fired.

The 'validating' event is documented [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.validating). It is a generic event that applies to many WinForms controls including textboxes.

Edit:

Here's a code sample for the code for Form1 if there are 4 textboxes and nothing else on a basic form:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As Object, e As CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
        Dim Input As String

        ' get input
        Input = Me.TextBox1.Text

        ' assume input is space delimited
        For Each Item As String In Input.Split(" ").ToList
            If IsNumeric(Item) Then
                If Convert.ToDouble(Item) > 2 Then
                    Me.TextBox2.Text = Me.TextBox2.Text.Replace(Item, String.Empty)
                    Me.TextBox3.Text = Me.TextBox3.Text.Replace(Item, String.Empty)
                    Me.TextBox4.Text = Me.TextBox4.Text.Replace(Item, String.Empty)
                End If
            End If
        Next

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: sorry im still not sure